# Can ngrx be made to enforce ordering?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm testing a prototype Angular 2 app using `ngrx`. In pretty much all cases an action has to get data from a back-end API asynchronously before it updates the state. I'm doing this in `ngrx/effects` using the standard approaches, by fetching the data and then creating another action to process the state using the fetched data (with a reducer of course)

What I am noticing is that the second actions are processed in the order in which the data is retrieved from the back end, not the order in which the action was initiated. This can give rise to some unfortunate effects.

Is there a standard way in `ngrx` of making sure actions, including dependent actions, are processed in the order in which they are dispatched?

Comment: Simplest method would probably be to wait to dispatch the second action till the first completed. You could even have one effect listen for the success of another.

Comment: @bygrace How do effects know about each other?

Comment: They don't and probably shouldn't. But one effect can emit an action that another can listen for.

Comment: Idk if there is a best practice. I'm a bit concerned about creating lengthy event chains with this approach.

Comment: Don't know if I understood correctly, but how about adding a marker on every first request, and when the HTTP request returns place the same marker in the payload before dispatching it to the second action, finally in your reducer have the logic to order the state based on some marker strategy.

Comment: It may be a case of bad design. Could you maybe provide us with some simplified example of what is actually happening in the system? Some "use-case" like sentences would help a lot.

Comment: Can you please add a sample app at stackblitz? To me it seems that `forkJoin` is what you are looking for. However i'm not sure of you'r requirement. Or at least please include here the code that is making the action calls. Please tell me if `forkJoin` fulfills your need so i'll add it as an answer :)

Comment: Any feedback @DJClayworth?

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely make sure that observables execute in sequence (one after the other in a serial manner).

We have `concat` operator where you can concatenate operators like concat(obs1$, ob2$). In this obs1$ will execute first and after that obs2$ will. Let say a `formControl` valueChange is emitting value and we are dispatching events for every Change.

And let say we have higher order observables which we want to execute in a sequence. In that case we can use `concatMap` operator.

```
this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    concatMap(value => this.http.get('url'))
)
```

Hope it will help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an ordered sequence then you need to use correlation id in your actions to distinguish different calls and connect together actions that cause backend requests with the actions of their responses.
Then you know sequence how they started and can transform sequence of responses in the same order.
And the most important question - how do effects know about each other?
The answer: through `this.actions$: Actions`, you can connect it with `switchMap` inside of an effect class and to perform `ofType` to detect a desired action.

```js
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.startSequence),

  // some activity here. for example
  switchMap(action => this.actions$.pipe(ofType(actions.causeRequest)),

  takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(actions.stopSequence))),
  repeat(),
);
```